# Vue components Event Handling

Tags: vue.js, event-handling, components, nuxt.js

I have a component button where I use that button almost everywhere in my site.

Its an SVG button with some animation on hover. The button works fine.

```js
<template> 
 <a class="button"
  @mouseover="buttonEnter"
  @mouseout="buttonLeave">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 180 60">
   <path ref="btnPath" d="..." />
  </svg>
  <span ref="btnSpan">
   <slot>Button slot</slot>
  </span>
 </a>
</template>

<script>
import { buttonEnter, buttonleave } from '../assets/animate'

export default {
 name: 'AnimButton',
 methods: {
  buttonEnter(event) {
   buttonEnter(this.$refs.btnPath, this.$refs.btnSpan)
  },
  buttonLeave(event) {
   const buttonSpan = event.currentTarget.querySelector('span')
   buttonleave(this.$refs.btnPath, this.$refs.btnSpan)
  },
 },
}
</script>
```

Now I wanna use this button as a submit button in my form.The hover events are happening, but seems the **@click** event is not triggering.

Probably i'm missing something bad.

```js
<form>
  <input type="email">
  <input type="subject">
  <input type="message">
  
  <anim-button type="submit" @click="submit">
   Submit
 </anim-button>

</form>

<script>
import AnimButton from '~/components/AnimButton.vue'

export default {
 components: {
  AnimButton,
 },
 methods: {
  submit: function() {
   console.log('submit')
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: did you try `@click.native` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can both use `@click.native` like suggested in comment ([see here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Listening-for-Native-Events-on-Components-with-v-on-changed)) or put `@click` in your **AnimButton**, `$emit` some event and catch this event in parent component.